# Non-native QFileDialog: set focus to file list box, rather than to file name line edit

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, widget, qfiledialog

I need to use `QFileDialog` in a non-native mode (in order to be able to have a multiselect functionality as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060868/extra-unwanted-selection-from-qfiledialog)).

However, in that mode it has a focus set to the filename edit line at its bottom. I have found this code, which I guess, results in such a behavior:

```cpp
//https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html
void QFileDialog::setVisible(bool visible)
{
    ...
    if (!d->nativeDialogInUse)
        d->qFileDialogUi->fileNameEdit->setFocus();

    QDialog::setVisible(visible);
}
```

However, I would like to set the focus to the file list box. i.e. tree view or list view, as otherwise the box looks grayish. I don't know why Qt developers set the focus to the file name line edit in the non-native mode. Maybe, there is a rationale behind this solution.

I have found a related question [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9163/how-to-set-focus-to-file-list-box-in-qfiledialog/6).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have `protected` `virtual` `QFileDialog::setVisible(bool)` reimplemented:

```cpp
#include "QtWidgets/QFileDialog"
#include "QtWidgets/QListView"
#include "QtWidgets/QTreeView"

class MyFileDialog final : public QFileDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyFileDialog(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : : QFileDialog(parent) {}

public: // QFileDialog
    ~MyFileDialog() override = default;

protected:
    void setVisible(bool isVisible) override
    {
        QFileDialog::setVisible(isVisible);

        auto* const listView{findChild<QListView*>("listView")};
        if (nullptr != listView)
        {
            listView->setFocus();
        }

        auto* const treeView{findChild<QTreeView*>()};
        if (nullptr != treeView)
        {
            treeView->setFocus();
        }
    }
};
```